# Setting up user queue system with vapix 3 api. Axis ip camera

Tags: javascript, html, queue, vapix

Setting up user queue system with vapix 3 api. Axis ip camera

trying to set up a basic camera API with user queuing system. Can not seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried different HTTP calls to do the queuing system still cant get it to work.

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="https://172.16.253.235/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?BoaProtPTZOperator=timeslive2018">


  <div class="invisipulldwn"> <iframe src="iframeControlButtons" class="iframeControlButtons" id="MyFrame"></iframe>
    <select id="IsolatedFrame4Queue">
      <option value="http://172.16.253.235/axis-cgi/com/ptzqueue.cgi?CtlQueuing=true&control=request&camera=1&UseCookie=yes"></option>
    </select> </div><!-- END:Invisipulldown -->
  <button onClick="window.location.href='http://172.16.253.235/axis-cgi/com/ptzqueue.cgi?CtlQueuing=true&control=drop&camera=1&UseCookie=yes">Request Control</button>




  <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">


    <form>

      <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="CNTRL-Release" ONCLICK="window.location.href='http://172.16.253.235/axis-cgi/com/ptzqueue.cgi?CtlQueuing=true&control=drop&camera=1&UseCookie=yes'">
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, especially define how it *does not work*. Do you have a stack trace of the error etc? Oh, and welcome by the way!

Comment: I am trying to set up the queueing system through the vapix api. Vapix was not good at explaining. How to do this so i have the ptz aspect of the camera working but when I try to set up the queuing system through http requests I cant get it to work.